# How does library size affects an application's load time and memory foot print?

Tags: linux, memory, embedded, posix, dlopen

Some other people in the office are discussing about reducing the memory footprint and load time by cutting out non-essential parts of an internal library into separate libraries, and load them on-demand.

I did some Googling tonight and learned that `ld.so` loads libraries with lazy binding, and both `ld.so` and `dlopen` loads the library with `mmap`. This seems to mean that those none-essential parts of the library are already loaded on-demand, i.e. as long as the functions are not used / data pages in the library are not read,

1. It doesn't take space and
2. It doesn't take time to load and allocate those pages.

So I thought they just need to make sure they don't actively touch all the non-essential components.
Is this true? Is this true (practically) for all `posix` systems?

Comment: What's the real problem you're trying to solve?  Is this app for tiny systems?  If not, can you just buy more memory?  How much memory are you using now and what's your end goal?

Comment: By "memory footprint", do you mean resident set size? Or virtual memory usage? Or what?

Comment: This is an embedded system. I totally agree with you, that this question is completely irrelevant if we are talking about a PC.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I care about virtual memory usage, although the more important thing is load time.

Comment: How much memory do you have available?  How much is being used now?  What's your target usage?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I don't know the system requirement, but this is a performance problem, not a functional one. Just like all performance problems, we don't want to spend time, and if possible, we don't want to take space. Given that my colleagues are discussing this problem, I can only imagine that they aren't meeting their expectation yet.

Comment: @mercurycc If you care about virtual memory usage, then you are wrong. They're *loaded* on demand, but they consume the same amount of virtual memory whether they're loaded or not. They consume virtual memory just by being mapped.

Comment: @mercurycc: if you don't know what the requirements are, you should stop working on this until  you do.  For example, if you need to save 95% of the used memory, the range of solutions is different from if you need to save 5%.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Am I wrong about space, or am I wrong about time too? Sure they take the same amount of VA chunk, but as long as the pages are not reloc'ed / data not read, there won't be any (or at least not much) disk reads to move them into memory, right?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I am more curious about how exactly ld.so work to save load time / space than actually solving my colleague's problems. It isn't my problem anyway :)

Comment: @mercurycc You're right about RAM, disk I/O, and time. You're wrong about virtual memory.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Post that (plus whatever elaboration you feel needed) as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Any library that directly links into your program or is a direct dependency still gets mapped and loaded at run time.  To see what libraries will be open, you can use `ldd some_program`.  Some of these will be indirect dependencies that will also be loaded.  To see only what the direct depencies are you can use `objdump -x my_program | grep NEEDED`.  Not only does every library have to be read from disk (can be relatively slow), but all the necessary symbols (sometimes many) from them must be mapped.

It may be that one dependency that isn't necessarily needed at startup, is pulling in the majority of your total library size. If you can split apart different capabilities into functional units that can be **loaded as modules**, it can be straight forward to reduce startup time and to some extent the memory footprint.

The easiest example I can come up with is an image viewer application where the GUI libraries are linked into the binary, but the actual loading of images is done by modules.  ([feh](https://github.com/derf/feh) would be be an example of this using Imlib2 or optionally gdk-pixbuf for the image loading).  This allows the main GUI to start up without ever loading libpng, libjpeg, libXPM, libcairo, librsvg, etc...  This reduces the startup time because none of those need to be loaded, and may never be loaded, thus reducing the memory footprint.

In C this is commonly done with `dlopen()`, `dlsym()` and `dlclose()` (embedded systems using a flat binary format can use a specially linked module) but most toolkits will have their own module implementation (for instance Gtk+ uses glib's cross-platform module loading).

It doesn't have to be that cut and dry.  You could just as easily split your initial GUI into parts and sequentially dlopen() them as an alternative to having a separate "splash screen".  I don't know of any example of a toolkit that allows this but one could even open an X11 window with title and dimensions, then load the GUI and associated libraries into that window.  You could load different binary format parsers depending on the file's extension/magic value or load different binary format generators depending on what format the user decides to Save_As.

Another alternative is to **statically link library dependencies** so that only the required symbols get loaded (as long as there are no licensing issues with doing so).  Why load up 100+ widgets, when you only use 10?  This works best with libraries that are built with static linking in mind such as musl-libc (glibc is notoriously useless for static linking).  Compiling with the -flto compiler flag (or -combine -fwhole-program on older versions of gcc) along with -ffunction-sections and -fdata-sections and linking with --gc-sections typically helps (I normally see 15-50% size reduction)  This is also a good option if you can't rely on the shared system libraries to be sane.